# Unable to open Hyperlink in Browser

Tags: c#, datagridview, hyperlink, wpfdatagrid

I have DataGridHyperlink column HyperLinks to images stored on disk. When i click on Hyperlink my image gets displayed successfully but i get this error "FAILED TO CONVERT RESOURCE INTO OBJECT".

My code for datagridhyperlink column is below.

below in code s_man_image is being retrieved from database which contains path of image.

```
       <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="CNIC" Binding="{Binding s_man_image}" Width="100" >
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="DataGrid_Click" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```

and below is code for event Handler.

```
     private void DataGrid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
          var hyperlink = e.OriginalSource as Hyperlink;
          if (hyperlink != null)
          {
              Process.Start(hyperlink.NavigateUri.ToString());
              e.Handled = true;
          }

     }
```

[i have debugged and attached snap here please have a look on it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpTr1.png)

Comment: Did you debug the code and check what you are getting in `e.OriginalSource`? Which line in the code throws the exception? Can you share the exception and it's InnerException details?

Comment: Process.Start(hyperlink.NavigateUri.ToString()); is throwing exception that failed to convert resource into object.

Comment: What value you are getting in e.OriginalSource? What value you are getting in `hyperlink.NavigateUri.ToString()`? I hope I am able to make myself clear now.

Comment: Sir i have debugged and attached snap in my question please have a look on it.

Comment: As you see in the debugger, the NavigateUri of huperlink is pointing to a local path of an image. And you are passing that path to process.start. Process.Start expect a path of an executable file. It can not run an image. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: Can you assist me that how can i provide executable path to Process.Start. I am stucked in this problem.

Comment: How can i convert local path to executable path to provide it in Process.Start()?